# Unable to get simple focus() function working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have a simple contact link in nav bar that listens for a click, triggers a function that focus() on the form input with id 'hello'. Getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at practice1.js:18

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home"><span class="active">Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#media">Media</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" id="hello">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<form>
    Full name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullName"><br>
    Message:<br>
    <textarea type="text" name="message" id="sidebar-message"></textarea><br>
    <button type="submit" name="message-submit" class="submit-button" href="#">Submit</button>
</form>

function contactFocus() {
    $('#fullName').focus();
}

var contactLink = document.getElementById('hello');
contactLink.addEventListener('click', contactFocus, false);
```

Comment: Sometimes errors tell you exactly what your problems is. Where exactly is the script that you are running located on the page in relation to the markup?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a *timing* problem: the line runs before the page fully executes.

Try this, in a more jQuery-y idiom:

```
$(() => {
  $("#hello").click(contactFocus);
});
```

**Edit:**
In more detail, the underlying problem is that the Javascript is run before the page has fully rendered, so the item with the id "hello" does not yet exist.

My changes are

- I arranged for the function to be run only once jQuery is ready; that's the meaning of the `$(fcn)` expression.  In my opinion, this is superior to using `$(document).ready()` -- the document being ready is not a widely understood concept.  The point is that *jQuery* ("$") is ready.
- I used `$("#hello")` instead of `document.getElementById('hello')`, they are roughly equivalent, but the former is the jQuery way to do it.
- For the same reason, I used `.click(f)` instead of `.addEventListener('click',f)`

Comment: Thanks that worked! Not sure why though. Can you explain?

Comment: Your script is most likely in your header, before your markup is defined.  The elements you are trying to find will not exist in the dom at the time it runs.  Which is why it works with the document ready, which delays the execution until the dom is parsed with all the markup data.  Alternatively if you included your script right before your </body> you wouldn't need to make this change at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your jQuery in a `$(document).ready()`
Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fullName').focus();
});
```

This waits for the page and CSS to finish loading before it executes the script.

Comment: Same as the other answer, just without arrow function.

Comment: Yea,  but its purpose is more clear and is better to practice it

Comment: That's a manner of opinion, and I disagree with the better practice notion.  $(() => {}), $(function), and $(document).ready(function) all perform the same logic.

Comment: Better practice if you're new to jQuery.  https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Ah, just found the comment.  Still, I consider it a manner of coding practice.  $(function) isn't that confusing to learn and is often used when showing new people in the jQuery freenode irc.

Comment: "Experienced developers sometimes use the shorthand $() for $( document ).ready(). If you are writing code that people who aren't experienced with jQuery may see, it's best to use the long form."  It's just advice.  It's not fact.  It's always good practice to write out functions and not use shorthand.  That's what they taught me in college.